# Is it possible to handle multiple Pop-ups in a single step?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[This page](http://www.globalsqa.com/samplepagetest/) has a button **Alert Box : Click Here**. If we click on this button it shows a pop-up and when we click on **OK** button there it's showing another pop-up.

My code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contact-form-2599']/form/button")).click();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

I am using the same code twice for clicking the pop-ups.

Is it possible to handle multiple pop-ups in a single step?

Comment: Can you define "one step"? And Do you have some sort of identifier for those alerts? Maybe you can loop on them and accept.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi You mean it is possible to works using loop?? Can you give me an example??

Comment: I have insufficient information to provide a good solution, but I will suggest something nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over all the possible named alerts that the `driver` can focus on with:

```
function closeAlerts() {
    // this aussmes that there is at least one alert
    try {
        let currentAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    // loop through the alerts and accept them
    while (currentAlert && currentAlert.accept instanceof Function) {
        currentAlert.accept();
        try {
            currentAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    }
}
closeAlerts();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If this does not work, try logging `driver.switchTo().alert()` in both cases where there is an alert and where there isn't one.

Comment: i'm getting an error "Cannot be resolved to a type” when attempting to use this code.

Comment: So i just modified the code...  Alert Myalert = driver.switchTo().alert();

  // loop through the alerts and accept them
  
  while (Myalert.equals(Myalert))
   try
  {
   Myalert.accept();
 
   Myalert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  }
   catch (NoAlertPresentException a) 
  {
    {
           break;
    }
  }

Comment: The code you pasted won't work, it not even JavaScript, Can you precisely indicate the scenario you are running to reproduce the error?

Comment: Sir basically i'm just a beginner in selenium web driver. Can you please look into this link http://www.globalsqa.com/samplepagetest/ it contans the button 'Alert box : Click Here' so when we click on the button two pop-ups are appeared so how can i handle this scenario?

Comment: The loop should suffise, but just to be sure, I will wrap it in a function and add a few `try catch` statements.

Answer (score -1):

This can be use with for loop also,

// It is set for 2 alerts

```
    for (int i=1; i<3; i++)
    {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();//Here it runs twice so two pop-ups can be accepted.
    }
```

Please check this too it's working for my code.